# Get Request in C# Returning 401 Not Authorised

Tags: c#, .net, http

Currently trying to do a Get request as part of a c# program. The request works fine on Postman as it uses a header for authorization. However I cannot get the code working for the program to use this header correctly in its Get request. I've had a good look around and tried various bits of code I've found but haven't managed to resolve it so any help would be appreciated!

```
public string Connect()
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string URI = "myURL.com";
                wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text");
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer OEMwNjI2ODQtMTc3OC00RkIxLTgyN0YtNzEzRkE5NzY3RTc3";//this is the entry code/key 
                string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(URI);
                return HtmlResult;
            }
        }
```

Above is one method inside the class.
Below is another attempt which is an extension method that gets passed the URL:

```
 public static string GetXml(this string destinationUrl)
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = 
                (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer 
                OEMwNjI2ODQtMTc3OC00RkIxLTgyN0YtNzEzRkE5NzY3RTc3";

                HttpWebResponse response;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    string responseStr = new 
                    StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                    return responseStr;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}({1})", 
                   response.StatusDescription, response.StatusCode));
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a user agent header of some description?

Comment: You should be using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`/`HttpWebRequest`

Comment: ok cool thanks but can't see any methods that add a header on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @AlexM. how would I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I recommend the very handy RestSharp package (find it on Nuget).

It turns your current code into something like

```
public string Connect()
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest("myURL.com", Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer OEMwNjI2ODQtMTc3OC00RkIxLTgyN0YtNzEzRkE5NzY3RTc3");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response.Content;
        }
```

It's much more succinct and easier to use (in my opinion) and thus lessens the likelihood of passing in or using incorrect methods.

If you're still having issues getting data back/connecting. Then using PostMan click `Code` in the upper right of PostMan and select the `C# (RestSharp)` option. Whatever is generated there matches exactly what PostMan is sending. Copy that over and you should get data back that matches your PostMan request.

Comment: Thanks- that has resolved the 401 although now it is returning blank...

Comment: @ET123 make sure to debug and see if response.Content contains anything. If it's null, then you'll need to address that with the "myURL.com". Also, don't forget to mark this as your answer since it resolved it.

Comment: well not sure if it's resolved yet as it's working on Postman still but this code isn't returning what it should.

Comment: added more detail to the answer to address your issue

Comment: thanks I'm nearly there now just need to parse it to a string but I'll give ya a tick for your help- thanks:)